# TIM2 overflow does not trigger TIM2_IRQHandler @ STM32G031J6

Tags: c, stm32

With the following code I want to make pin 5 (PA11) of an STM32G031J6M6 blink at 50 kHz. To do this, I configured TIM2 to overflow every 10 us. This is to call an ISR ("TIM2_IRGHandler") that toggles the level of PA11.
Now everything actually works fine: the toggle works and TIM2 counts to 10, resets and starts counting again. *The problem now is, that my ISR is not called when TIM2 overflows. Instead, the program simply "crashes"*. I guess it enters some "default handler" on TIM2 overflow.

(The code is compiled as C code and **not** C++.)

```c
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <stm32g031xx.h>

/*!
 * \brief Configures pin 5 ("PA11") as digital output.
 */
void config_output(void) {
  RCC->IOPENR |= RCC_IOPENR_GPIOAEN;
  GPIOA->MODER &= ~(0x3u << (11 * 2));
  GPIOA->MODER |= (0x1u << (11 * 2));
  GPIOA->OTYPER &= ~(0x1u << (11 * 1));
}

/*!
 * \brief Configures TIM2 overflow with 10 us period (-> 100 kHz).
 */
void config_blink_timer(void) {
  //Enable the TIM2 clock.
  RCC->APBENR1 |= RCC_APBENR1_TIM2EN;

  //Make sure the timer's "counter" is off.
  TIM2->CR1 &= ~TIM_CR1_CEN;

  //Reset the peripheral.
  RCC->APBRSTR1 |= (RCC_APBRSTR1_TIM2RST);
  RCC->APBRSTR1 &= ~(RCC_APBRSTR1_TIM2RST);

  //Set the timer prescaler/autoreload timing registers.
  TIM2->PSC = 16 - 1; //-> 16 MHz / 16 = 1 MHz
  TIM2->ARR = 10 - 1; //-> 1/1 MHz * 10 = 10 us (100 kHz)

  //Send an update event to reset the timer and apply settings.
  TIM2->EGR |= TIM_EGR_UG;

  //Enable TIM2 interrupts.
  NVIC_EnableIRQ(TIM2_IRQn);
}

/*!
 * \brief Enables the "Cycle Timer", which will now fire interrupts that trigger
 * execution of the "App Loop" (--> \c TIM2_IRQHandler()).
 */
void run_app(void) {
  //Clear TIM2_IRQn update interrupt,
  TIM2->SR &= ~TIM_SR_UIF;

  //Enable the hardware interrupt.
  TIM2->DIER |= TIM_DIER_UIE;

  //Enable the timer.
  TIM2->CR1 |= TIM_CR1_CEN;
}

/*!
 * \brief Initializes any peripheral being used.
 */
void init(void) {
  //Disable interrupts.
  __disable_irq();

  config_output();
  config_blink_timer();

  //Enable interrupts.
  __enable_irq();
}

/*!
 * \brief Initializes the system and runs the application.
 */
int main(void) {
  init();

  run_app();

  while(1)
    __WFI();

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

/*!
 * \brief This IRQ handler will be triggered every 10 us by the "Blink Timer".
 * This "time base" is used to blink a LED with a defined pattern (50 kHz,
 * 50% DS).
 */
void TIM2_IRQHandler(void) {
  //Toggle PA11 (pin 5).
  GPIOA->ODR ^= (0x1u << 11);

  //Clear TIM2 update interrupt flag.
  TIM2->SR &= ~TIM_SR_UIF;

  //Power-down until next "tick"/interrupt.
  __WFE();
}
```

Comment: I don't remember this hardware but are you supposed to call `TIM2->SR &= ~TIM_SR_UIF;` repeatedly from the background program? Isn't that the very flag your interrupt is looking for?

Comment: Yes, the flag has to be cleared by software. It does not get cleared automatically/by hardware.

Comment: ...but isn't that the flag that your ISR is based upon and therefore it should only be cleared from the ISR?

Comment: @Lundin `run_app` isn't called in a loop.

Comment: Doing a WFE in the IRQ handler seems like a recipe for a hang, what if you remove that?

Comment: Right, misleading name. But then maybe this is simply the usual "I wrote an ISR but didn't register it in the vector table, why isn't it called?" FAQ

Comment: @hobbs You seem right - I removed it. However, this does not affect the error.

Comment: @Lundin The startup file is the one automatically generated by Cube IDE and definitely contains the vector.

Comment: Try calling the ISR function directly from main as a sanity check.

Comment: Some brief googling: isn't `TIM2->EGR` used to trigger an event regardless of timer settings? Doesn't sound like something one should do before registring the ISR with `NVIC_EnableIRQ`. What happens if you comment out that EGR line?

Comment: @TomV If in **main()** I comment out **run_app();** and then in the forever loop call **TIM2_IRQHandler()** repeatetly, the program works as expected. I can see a square signal of around 216 kHz at pin 5. (Maybe quite suspiciously slow???)

Comment: @Lundin Commenting out the "EGR line" does not really change anything. I think this line might be unnecessary, but it's not causing the issue.

Comment: Sounds like you should troubleshoot your system clock next.

Comment: @Lundin I don't exactly understand what you mean. But, I can tell that the assumed default 16 MHz from HSI16 (see [RM0444](https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/rm0444-stm32g0x1-advanced-armbased-32bit-mcus-stmicroelectronics.pdf), pg. 163) are driving TIM2 just as expected. If I disable global interrupts, but call the IRQ Handler from the main/forever loop each time the overflow flag gets set, I get more or less exact 50 kHz.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, the guys in this (German) forum [(-> link to thread)](https://www.mikrocontroller.net/topic/526172#6858618) put me on the right track and finally answered the question: We can fix the Problem by explicitly setting priority for TIM2_IRQn to "0". Instead of treating symptoms, however, it would be better to tackle the cause, which in this case can actually only be SysTick.
However, I can no longer reproduce the problem with the original code ... If someone knows the answer to this strange phenomenon, he is of course welcome.

**But basically the problem is solved for me now.** The following code works fine:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <stm32g031xx.h>

/*!
 * \brief Configures pin 5 ("PA11") as digital output.
 */
void config_output(void) {
  RCC->IOPENR |= RCC_IOPENR_GPIOAEN;
  GPIOA->MODER &= ~(0x3u << (11 * 2));
  GPIOA->MODER |= (0x1u << (11 * 2));
  GPIOA->OTYPER &= ~(0x1u << (11 * 1));
}

/*!
 * \brief Configures TIM2 overflow with 10 us period (-> 100 kHz).
 */
void config_blink_timer(void) {
  //Enable the TIM2 clock.
  RCC->APBENR1 |= RCC_APBENR1_TIM2EN;

  //Make sure the timer's "counter" is off.
  TIM2->CR1 &= ~TIM_CR1_CEN;

  //Reset the peripheral.
  RCC->APBRSTR1 |= (RCC_APBRSTR1_TIM2RST);
  RCC->APBRSTR1 &= ~(RCC_APBRSTR1_TIM2RST);

  //Set the timer prescaler/autoreload timing registers.
  TIM2->PSC = 16 - 1; //-> 16 MHz / 16 = 1 MHz
  TIM2->ARR = 10 - 1; //-> 1/1 MHz * 10 = 10 us (100 kHz)

  //Send an update event to reset the timer and apply settings.
  TIM2->EGR |= TIM_EGR_UG;

  //Enable TIM2 interrupts and set priority.
  NVIC_EnableIRQ(TIM2_IRQn);
  NVIC_SetPriority(TIM2_IRQn, 0);
}

/*!
 * \brief Enables the "Cycle Timer", which will now fire interrupts that trigger
 * execution of the "App Loop" (--> \c TIM2_IRQHandler()).
 */
void start_app(void) {
  //Clear TIM2_IRQn update interrupt,
  TIM2->SR &= ~TIM_SR_UIF;

  //Enable the hardware interrupt.
  TIM2->DIER |= TIM_DIER_UIE;

  //Enable the timer.
  TIM2->CR1 |= TIM_CR1_CEN;
}

/*!
 * \brief Initializes any peripheral being used.
 */
void init(void) {
  //Disable interrupts.
  __disable_irq();

  config_output();
  config_blink_timer();

  //Enable interrupts.
  __enable_irq();
}

/*!
 * \brief Initializes the system and runs the application.
 */
int main(void) {
  init();

  start_app();

  while(1)
    __WFI();

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

/*!
 * \brief This IRQ handler will be triggered every 10 us by the "Blink Timer".
 * This "time base" is used to blink a LED with a defined pattern (50 kHz,
 * 50% DS).
 */
void TIM2_IRQHandler(void) {
  //Clear TIM2 update interrupt flag.
  TIM2->SR &= ~TIM_SR_UIF;

  //Toggle PA11 (pin 5).
  GPIOA->ODR ^= (0x1u << 11);
}
```